# window.onload is not fired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onload

I am writing a chrome extension for practicing, which is basically remembers your password in a website the next time. However, I have a problem with running the code. window.onload, document.onload, none of them are fires my `remember()` function. Checked other answers, none of them could help. Checked if it gets overridden by actual code in the website, only body.onload is being overridden. Here is my code:

```
window.onload = remember;

var remember = function() {
    var name = localStorage["name"];
    var pw = localStorage["pw"];

    if(pw != undefined && name != undefined) 
    {
        document.sqrl.login_username.value = name;
        document.sqrl.secretkey.value = pw;
    };

    document.sqrl.onsubmit = function() {
        localStorage["name"] = document.sqrl.login_username.value;
        localStorage["pw"] = document.sqrl.secretkey.value;
    };
};
```

It executes the first two lines, but then does not enter inside the function, as I tested it with debugger in Chrome. What is missing in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing to a variable before it is declared / visible in the scope. Do

```js
var remember = function() {
  ...
  ...
};

window.onload = remember;
```

instead. Fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9pcL3jz3/**

Comment: If I select the onload option on the right, it is not working again. Do you think I also should not use window.onload in my code?  Because it still does not work in my extension.

http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lsua8f/

Comment: @BurakÖzmen, you had "wrap onload" set in the fiddle, remove this (your own site is not wrapped anyway) -> http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lsua8f/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

- you use `remember` before defining it
- your `document.sqrl.login_username.value` and `document.sqrl.secretkey.value` values depend on `name` and `pw`, `name` and `pw` depend on `localStorage` values, which in turn `are set based on your`document.sqrl`objects. If you set document.sqrl.login_username.value` and `sqrl.secretkey.value` somewhere else before the `onsubmit` is executed, then this is actually not a problem
- you try to directly access `"name"` and `"pw"` from `localStorage`, I believe you cannot do that. Use the `getItem` and `setItem` functions instead

Suggested code:

```
var remember = function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var pw = localStorage.getItem("pw");

    if(pw != undefined && name != undefined) 
    {
        document.sqrl.login_username.value = name;
        document.sqrl.secretkey.value = pw;
    };

    document.sqrl.onsubmit = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("name", document.sqrl.login_username.value);
        localStorage.setItem("pw", document.sqrl.secretkey.value);
    };
};

window.onload = remember;
```

EDIT:
I have read the comment of Xan and have tested the following code in my console:

```
localStorage["foo"] = "bar";
```

After reloading the page I have checked the value of `localStorage["foo"]` and it was `"bar"` indeed. Therefore, Xan was right and my third point is invalid indeed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @LajosArpad Changed my code accordingly, still no use.

http://jsfiddle.net/rc8v72o4/

Comment: @BurakÖzmen, can you check the name and pw values in your localStorage using your console? Can you tell us what happens with document.sqrl outside your remember function? Can you share the relevant part of your html?

Comment: @LajosArpad it is not even going in, so i dont think that there is this relevant values in localStorage. Here is jsfiddle with HTML from the website I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/rc8v72o4/

Answer (score -1):

Try this?

```
 window.onload = remember;

    var remember = function() {

        var name = localStorage.name;
        var pw = localStorage.pw;

        if(pw !== undefined && name !== undefined) 
        {
            document.sqrl.login_username.value = name;
            document.sqrl.secretkey.value = pw;
        }

        document.sqrl.onsubmit = function() {
            localStorage.name = document.sqrl.login_username.value;
            localStorage.pw = document.sqrl.secretkey.value;
        };
    };
```